# How to enable the text area for one value of an array by clicking the button for that value using javascript/angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, frontend

I need to enable the text area for one value of an array by clicking the button for that value

I hve tried by best to get it resolved but my solution result is like

The text area is enabled for every value in an array

The step which i followed is described below

**STEP 1 :
app.component.html**

I am displaying the array in the html file

```html
<tbody *ngFor="let items of sectionDetails">
    <tr *ngIf="items.sectionName == item">

        <td>
            {{items.question}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{items.answer }}
        </td>
        <td>
           <textarea *ngIf=edit"></textarea>
           <span *ngIf="!edit">--</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            {{items.updated_at | date:"MM/dd/yyyy"}}
        </td>
        <td>
            --
        </td>
        <td>
        <button class="btn btn-primary"  (click)="editAnswer()" disabled>
                <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        </td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**STEP 2 :
app.component.ts**

I am writing the logic in the

```
edit : boolean = false

editAnswer() {

this.edit = true

}
```

I need to display the text area only for that row for which button is clicked

Expected Result :

If a user clicks on the edit button of the row , the text area should be displayed for that particular row

Actual result :

Now , If a user clicks on the edit button of the row , the text area is displayed for all row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to add a property to your 'item' object and name it 'edit'. By default you could set this property to 'false'.

```
editAnswer(item) {
  item.edit=true;
}
```

When you click the button in that row, you can change the value of 'item.edit=true'. 
And in the table also use 'item.edit'

```
<td>
   <textarea *ngIf=item.edit"></textarea>
   <span *ngIf="!item.edit">--</span>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks pajtim , but is there any other way .I have tried this but not working

Comment: you are welcome!  could you please update your question to let me see what you exactly did.  best way would be to open a https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ikk45k with a running example.

Answer (score 0):

do below changes in your template

```
<textarea *ngIf=item.isEdit"></textarea>

    <button class="btn btn-primary"  (click)="editAnswer(items)" disabled>
                                <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>
```

In ts file

```
 editAnswer(item) {
      item.isEdit=true;
    }
```

let me know still you have problem

thanks

Comment: here I have added one more property/field in `this.sectionDetails` which name is `isEdit` which will decide row,which row you want to edit?

Comment: @pajtim i think it's not same, because above answer dose not have button template with items parametrs, by the way it's solved the problem so i am happy